# Unable to connect to BLE: [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid error

Tags: ios, arduino, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, xpc

I am using an Adafruit nRF8001 bluetooth module with an Arduino Nano micro controller. The goal is to connect the nRF8001 to an iOS application. This connection was successfully made using an Arduino Uno. However, when switching to the Arduino Nano, the connection cannot be made and the following is printed to the XCode console: "[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid".

The class that attempts to make the connection implements CBCentralManagerDelegate and CBPeripheralDelegate.

To find the error, I write to the console in each of the delegate functions. I found that the "XPC connection invalid" message is printed 0.004 seconds after initializing the CBCentralManager object. After this, the centralManagerDidUpdateState delegate method is called, and the CBCentralManager passed to this function has a state of CBManagerStatePoweredOn. Then I use the CBCentralManager to call scanForPeripheralsWithServices. This is the last message that I receive because the didDiscoverPeripheral method is never called.

On a separate post, I found that other people found success by adding a privacy description. I added a "Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description" in the project's Info.plist without any luck.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Use the LightBlue app on your device to confirm that your Arduino is advertising correctly. It sounds to me like it isn't.